# SQL (postgres) - Recursive view for all parents of a child

Tags: postgresql, view, recursive

**Solved**: Solution from crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149082/8082262

I have two tables: `community2collection(collection_id,community_id)` and `community2community(child_comm_id,parent_comm_id)`.

I'm trying to create a recursive view that for any given collection (`collection_id`) will return a list of the direct community parent (community_id), as well as any ancestor of the direct community (so recursively going through `community2community`.

I had

```
CREATE VIEW hierarchical_comcoltree
AS
    WITH RECURSIVE comcoltree AS
      (SELECT collection_id,
              community_id AS any_community_id
       FROM community2collection
       UNION ALL SELECT com2col.collection_id,
                        com2com.parent_comm_id AS any_community_id
       FROM community2collection com2col
       INNER JOIN community2community com2com
       ON com2com.child_comm_id = com2col.community_id)
    SELECT * FROM comcoltree;
```

But this only retrieves the direct community, as well as its first parent, but not further ancestors, with query

```
SELECT collection_id,
       any_community_id
FROM hierarchical_comcoltree
WHERE collection_id = '13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49'
ORDER BY collection_id ASC;
```

Any help would be appreciated, tried a few variations (as well as with a function), but haven't found one that works yet...

**Test data**

`community2collection`

| collection_id | community_id |
| --- | --- |
| 13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49 | 17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978 |
| cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0 | 88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24 |

`community2community`

| child_comm_id | parent_comm_id |
| --- | --- |
| 17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978 | ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a |
| ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a | 05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f |
| 88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24 | 726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e |
| 726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e | ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a |
| ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a | 05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f |

- Expected results view for first collection `'13081d45-dcdc-4e4d-94a5-33056c9f0c49'`

=> `'17475c16-a03e-4f5f-8928-bef6a4813978'`, `'ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a'` and `'05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f'`

=> Missing last one with current solution

- Expected results view for second collection `'cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0'`

=> `'88aa4abd-d024-47d2-a1a4-bdb3d744dd24'`, `'726a8531-4441-4feb-a8fc-b089445bc39e'`, `'ae12f497-b7de-4cb6-939f-70968a5e7b0a'` and `'05810e9b-cf09-4c13-a750-297cca5fd84f'`

=> Missing last two ones with current solution

Testing with:

```
WITH RECURSIVE comcoltree AS
  (SELECT collection_id,
          community_id AS any_community_id
   FROM community2collection
   UNION ALL SELECT com2col.collection_id,
                    com2com.parent_comm_id AS any_community_id
   FROM community2collection com2col
   INNER JOIN community2community com2com ON com2com.child_comm_id = com2col.community_id)
SELECT collection_id,
       any_community_id
FROM comcoltree
WHERE any_community_id = 'cbc98392-ba86-4ed3-b477-5a4a7652f3f0'
ORDER BY collection_id ASC;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solution from crossposting the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149082/8082262